# Unable to show HTML select option initially when starting the page in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

in my ts file I've defined this :

```
  statuses = [
    { id: 1, name: "Approved" },
    { id: 2, name: "Created" },
    { id: 3, name: "Rejected" },
    { id: 4, name: "Cancelled" },
  ];
```

in my HTML here is the code

```
<div class="col-1" id="statusFilter">
      <label class="font-weight-bold text-secondary" for="statusFilter">Filter By Status:</label>
      <select
        [(ngModel)]="statusFilter"
        class="form-control"
        (change)="setStatusFilter()">
        <option value="'Choose'" disabled selected><strong> Choose Filter: </strong></option>
        <option *ngFor="let status of statuses" [value]="status.name">
            {{ status.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

what appears in the Angular App is this empty select,
my goal is to make the first  tag show its value 'Choose Filter: ' before selecting anything

here is how it currently appears:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fANlI.png)

and this is what I need it to appear
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH0SU.png)

and for information this is how the select list would appear if I click it, I would be able to see that disabled option inside of it only if clicked but not by default
[select list clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsoLC.png)

Any idea what i'm doing wrong in here ?

Comment: use `<option [value]="null" disabled hidden>Choose Filter</option>` and declare your variable `statusFilter:string=null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should fill **statusFilter** with "Choose" value in the "ts" file.

```js
statusFilter = 'Choose';
```

Comment: Good luck @Angular Dev.